# How To Update an RSS Feed in Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, rss

I'm designing an app that needs to have access to an RSS feed at all times. I need to be able to access this feed in the background, while the app is not running. I already have all the code I need to access the feed and extract the info I need.

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the exact implementation because I haven't tried it myself but Apple introduced background tasks with new SDK.

So basically you register for a background task like downloading content in your `AppDelegate`'s

`- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application`

and when application becomes active you check to see if there was any new content. Again, this is a very raw explanation but hopefully should get you started.

**EDIT*****
Check this out :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios

Although this does not talk about download content in the background

Comment: so there is no way that I could update the content say, every 5 minutes or something?